# Find the greatest common divisor of two consecutive terms of the sequence an=100+n^2.

Tags: sequences-and-series, problem-solving

Looking at sequences a=u+n^2, that there is a common divisor of 4u+1 between a2u and a2u+1, and now i need to prove that this is the greatest common divisor between terms au and au+1.
This is a part where i'm stuck, i know that au+1 - au is equal to 2n+1, but dont know where to go next?

Comment: Please use the dollar sign markups to put your expression into Latex. I take it you mean sequences of the form $a_{n} = u + n^{2}$ for some (non-negative?) integer $u$. What does au and au+1 mean? Is the first one $a_{n}u$ or $a_{u}$? Is a2u+1 $a_{2}u + 1$ or $a_{2u+1}$. In this case it can be guessed from the question but it is still a good habit to get into

Answer (score 4):

Fix $n$ and let $d$ be the common divisor of $a_{n} = 100 + n^{2}$ and $a_{n+1}=100 + (n+1)^{2}$. Then $d$ divides their difference 
$$
a_{n+1} - a_{n} = 2n+1.
$$
Furthermore, it divides the following linear combination:
$$
2a_{n} - n(2n+1) = 200 + 2n^{2} - 2n^{2} - n = 200 - n.
$$
Again, $d$ divides the linear combination
$$
2(200 - n) + (2n + 1) = 400 + 1 = 401.
$$
Since $401$ is prime, the only posibilities for $d$ are $1$ and $401$.

One can show that $401$ divides $100+n^{2}$ if and only if $n$ has residue $200$ or $201$ when divided by $401$. Then, the answer is:
$$
d = \begin{cases}
401 \text{ if $n$ has residue $200$ or $201$ when divided by $401$,}\\
~~1~~ \text{ in any other case}.
\end{cases}
$$